# C# conditional reference in solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am developing a C# application which uses a .tlb file as reference in its solution, which should be installed by another application - however I've recently discovered such use cases, where this other application would not be installed. In these cases my program fails to run correctly, my installer (made with [Microsoft Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)) throws the following error:

[image]

I suspect the behavior above is due to an initializer subclass which is called by the installer. I want this initializer class only call the discussed .tlb as reference, if it is actually useable/installed - so in case it's actually there, since it is only related to that other application which would install it to the user computer. How can I achieve this "conditional referencing" in my initializer.cs?

The exact code part:

```
using NGOptMan // This should be conditional or the line actually using it;
...
var optMan = (IOptionsManager)Activator.
 CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SIDEXISNG.OptionsManager")); 
 // This is the only command where I would use this .tlb.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `dynamic` which allows you to utilise COM objects but without a type library.

Change:

`var optMan = (IOptionsManager)Activator.CreateInstance(...)`

to

```
dynamic foo = Activator.
 CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SIDEXISNG.OptionsManager")); 

if (foo == null)
    return;  // failed

// Success
var optMan = (IOptionsManager)foo;  // Now cast using the typelib
```

NOTE the use of `dynamic` and the removal of the cast.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Using this method, I'm still missing the COM object, since the application that would install it is not installed on my PC. Is it unavoidable to install this application (installing the .tlb as COM object) to my PC if I want to be able to build my project? @MickyD

Comment: @Viktor depending on how much you use the COM object, you can completely remove the TLB reference from your project and just use **dynamic** everywhere.  That should solve your problem.  The only problem is that you’ll lose Intelisense whilst coding.